# PayPal - Lost the access token of REST API

Tags: paypal, payment

I am researching about integrating PayPal to my app using React Native. I am able to make it work. Following, after taking a good look on the document of PayPal I have a question:

If a hacker gets the `access token`, can he get money from buyer or business (create a fake order or something similar)?

According to the api, I see we need the `approval_url`, people have to approve that "OK, I am willing to pay these stuffs", then we can continue the payment process.

Following, I guess although the hacker gets our `access token`, he would be stopped when no one approves the payment.

Please feel free to correct me if there is anything wrong in my opinion.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: **If a hacker gets the access token, can he get money from buyer or business (create a fake order or something similar)?** have you tried to ask paypal support? personally, i'd put the payment logic on server side, without dumping any single key to client side.

Comment: @BagusTesa: thank you for a quick comment. I will try to ask PayPal support and will follow your suggestion if there is no reply from PayPal